# How can numbered files be moved and renamed to subsequent numbered files to correct directory?

Tags: files, directory, mv, numbering

In ~/wrongdir there are mpv-shot0001.jpg, mpv-shot0002.jpg, mpv-shot0003.jpg, mpv-shot0004.jpg, mpv-shot0005.jpg

where the screenshot key was pressed when a mpv was initiated in ~/wrongdir.

The screenshots need added to ~/correctdir where there are screenshots already from mpv-shot0001.jpg to mpv-shot9001.jpg.

A mere `mv ~/wrongdir/mpv-shot* ~/correctdir/` would clobber the files in ~/correctdir.

How can the screenshot files from ~/wrongdir be appended to the list of numbered screenshot files in ~/correctdir, following on the existing number sequence (in this example, as mpv-shot9002.jpg to mpv-shot9006.jpg)?

Answer (score 1):

With the zsh shell:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv -n 'wrongdir/(mpv-shot)(<1->)(.jpg)' \
       'correctdir/$1${(l[4][0])$(( $2 + 9001 ))}$3'
```

(remove the `-n` (dry-run) if happy).